# Jquery Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: jquery

I get the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` an error in google chrome. I know that mean, but I don't understand how to fix that error.

```
$(function(){
    $('.hunbun').readmore(function(){
        speed: 1000,
        collapsedHeight: 200, // < here get the that error
        moreLink: '<a href="#">read more</a>',
        lessLink: '<a href="#">close</a>'
    });
});
```

Comment: do you understand javascript syntax? in your function body you just wrote `speed: 1000,`, that's not right

Comment: Don't understand javascript syntax

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have syntax error: `.readmore` call requires object parameter you pass the function reference and in function body you write what you should be writing as object:

```
$(function(){
    $('.hunbun').readmore({
        speed: 1000,
        collapsedHeight: 200, // < here get the that error
        moreLink: '<a href="#">read more</a>',
        lessLink: '<a href="#">close</a>'
    });
});
```

remove `function()` from second line

Comment: I try that but get the error ==> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).readmore is not a function

Comment: <script>
$(function(){
    $('.hunbun').readmore({    //Uncaught TypeError: $(...).readmore is not a function

Comment: you should include it after jquery

Comment: Yes, i include the <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/readmore.js"></script> and <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: you should include jquery first, next readmore.js it matters because readmore uses jquery

Comment: I've set up jsfiddle for you, included jquery and readmorejs, pasted code I gave to you, please fill with your html content update and comment updated link version https://jsfiddle.net/Lj7Ldfb8/

Comment: Thank you !!     I will try that ,

Comment: not try just add html part, to let me see the problem better, to help u

Comment: there add only html part? my files is php files and data is from databases

Comment: you can copy from browser, if problem is in html and not in php

Comment: does it gives the same error? or different one at this time?

Comment: I was found what is problems , this file <script type="text/javascript"  src="../js/lib.min.js"></script> on the  my footer file

Comment: No idea how do work that, delete my src="../js/lib.min.js"> file working ,but i must need to src="../js/lib.min.js"> file

Comment: what it does? whats tht lib? is it what u write or got form internet?

Comment: that is do animation and scroll, and it is  Script Library got from  internet copy to my local file

Comment: I have to see the page, if it's remote give me link address where i can check it.

Comment: that is  only see my local ,not update server , but i will send  you  lib file

Comment: I'd better see everything in action, but u can add it to jsfiidle I posted. and also add some html to see real working example

Comment: u have to copy that link, I can't see it directly from jsfiddle site

Comment: Yes, it's working perfectly  in the https://jsfiddle.net/,    but not working my local